# Update panel and Jquery Plugin Issue

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am using Jquery Multiselect Plug in

I have put the plugin in update panel

But when page postback plugin stop working

for this i have used following statement

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    Sys.Application.add_load(CallAgain);
</script>
```

call again function is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function CallAgain() {              
        $("select").multiselect().multiselectfilter();
     }
</script>
```

Now plugin is loading after post back, but the problem is page gets hanged at each post back

There are two errors in error console:

> 1. Error: ReferenceError: Sys is not defined
> 2. Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error
>      occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code
>      returned from the server was: 500

Comment: Do you see any error in the console?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward I have updated the post with the errors i am getting in error console